# Uint8Array indexOf method that allows to search for byte sequences

Tags: javascript, optimization, node.js

```
Uint8Array.prototype.indexOfMulti = function(searchElements, fromIndex) {
    fromIndex = fromIndex || 0;

    var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this, searchElements[0], fromIndex);
    if(searchElements.length === 1 || index === -1) {
        // Not found or no other elements to check
        return index;
    }

    for(var i = index, j = 0; j < searchElements.length && i < this.length; i++, j++) {
        if(this[i] !== searchElements[j]) {
            return this.indexOfMulti(searchElements, index + 1);
        }
    }

    return (i === index + searchElements.length) ? index : -1;
};
```

It works fine but I wonder if I missed any important case or if anyone sees a way to optimize this.

Answer (score 4):

First things first. This code is fairly difficult to read. `indexOfMulti` could mean

- You're searching for any one of multiple values.
- You're searching for all occurrences of a value (less likely -- might be `indicesOf` or `findAll`).
- You're searching for the first occurrence of a sequence.

I'd name this something like `find`, `findSequence`, `findSubstring`. I'd also rename `searchElements` to something like `needle`, `targetSequence`.

---

You have two different efficiency issues here.

First, if this code is running in an implementation without tail-call optimization (I can't tell if *any* do, much less whether it's common), your memory usage may blow up whenever the first part of `needle` is common in your `haystack` but the full `needle` isn't found, because you'll blow up the stack. Better to implement this non-recursively.

Second, you've chosen the naive string search algorithm (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm). It will work fine when `needle` and `haystack` are small, or when prefixes of `needle` are rare in `haystack`, but it will be quite slow on the following example:

```
haystack = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab";
needle = "aaaab";
haystack.findSequence(needle);
```

You'd be better off selecting one of the other algorithms in that wikipedia article; a good choice is [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Boyer-Moore: https://gist.github.com/etrepum/6235082

[Click here for a cleaner typescript implementation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20needleType%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20Uint8Array%20%7C%20ArrayBuffer%3B%0Atype%20haystackType%20%3D%20ArrayBuffer%20%7C%20Uint8Array%3B%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Implementation%20of%20Boyer-Moore%20substring%20search%20ported%20from%20page%20772%20of%0A%2F%2F%20Algorithms%20Fourth%20Edition%20(Sedgewick%2C%20Wayne)%0A%2F%2F%20http%3A%2F%2Falgs4.cs.princeton.edu%2F53substring%2FBoyerMoore.java.html%0A%2F*%0AUSAGE%3A%0A%20%20%20%2F%2F%20needle%20should%20be%20ASCII%20string%2C%20ArrayBuffer%2C%20or%20Uint8Array%0A%20%20%20%2F%2F%20haystack%20should%20be%20an%20ArrayBuffer%20or%20Uint8Array%0A%0A%20%20%20const%20boyerMoore%20%3D%20new%20BoyerMoore(needle)%3B%0A%20%20%20const%20indexes%20%3D%20boyerMoore.findIndexes(haystack)%3B%0A*%2F%0A%0Aclass%20BoyerMoore%20%7B%0A%20%20private%20search%3A%20((txtBuffer%3A%20needleType%2C%20start%3F%3A%20number%2C%20end%3F%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20number%20)%3B%0A%20%20private%20skip%3A%20number%3B%0A%0A%20%20constructor(needle%3A%20needleType)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bthis.search%2C%20this.skip%5D%20%3D%20this.boyerMoore(needle)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20public%20findIndex(haystack%3A%20haystackType)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.search(haystack)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20public%20findIndexes(haystack%3A%20haystackType)%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20indexes%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%20this.search(haystack)%3B%20i%20!%3D%3D%20-1%3B%20i%20%3D%20this.search(haystack%2C%20i%20%2B%20this.skip))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20indexes.push(i)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20indexes%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20private%20asUint8Array(input%3A%20Uint8Array%20%7C%20string%20%7C%20ArrayBuffer)%3A%20Uint8Array%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(input%20instanceof%20Uint8Array)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20input%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(typeof(input)%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20naive%20transform%20only%20supports%20ASCII%20patterns.%20UTF-8%20support%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20not%20necessary%20for%20the%20intended%20use%20case%20here.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20uint8Array%3A%20Uint8Array%20%3D%20new%20Uint8Array(input.length)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20input.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20charCode%20%3D%20input.charCodeAt(i)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(charCode%20%3E%20127)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20TypeError('Only%20ASCII%20patterns%20are%20supported')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20uint8Array%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20charCode%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20uint8Array%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Assume%20that%20it's%20already%20something%20that%20can%20be%20coerced.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Uint8Array(input)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20private%20boyerMoore(patternBuffer)%3A%20%5B((txtBuffer%3A%20needleType%2C%20start%3F%3A%20number%2C%20end%3F%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20number%20)%2C%20number%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20pattern%20%3D%20this.asUint8Array(patternBuffer)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20M%3A%20number%20%3D%20pattern.length%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(M%20%3D%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20TypeError('patternBuffer%20must%20be%20at%20least%201%20byte%20long')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20radix%0A%20%20%20%20const%20radix%3A%20number%20%3D%20256%3B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20rightmost_positions%3A%20Int32Array%20%3D%20new%20Int32Array(radix)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20position%20of%20the%20rightmost%20occurrence%20of%20the%20byte%20c%20in%20the%20pattern%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20c%3A%20number%20%3D%200%3B%20c%20%3C%20radix%3B%20c%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20-1%20for%20bytes%20not%20in%20pattern%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20rightmost_positions%5Bc%5D%20%3D%20-1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20j%20%3D%200%3B%20j%20%3C%20M%3B%20j%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20rightmost%20position%20for%20bytes%20in%20pattern%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20rightmost_positions%5Bpattern%5Bj%5D%5D%20%3D%20j%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20function%20boyerMooreSearch(txtBuffer%3A%20needleType%2C%20start%3A%20number%20%3D%200%2C%20end%3F%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Return%20offset%20of%20first%20match%2C%20-1%20if%20no%20match.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20text%20%3D%20this.asUint8Array(txtBuffer)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(end%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20end%20%3D%20text.length%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20pat%20%3D%20pattern%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20right%20%3D%20rightmost_positions%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20lastIndex%20%3D%20end%20-%20pat.length%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20lastPatIndex%20%3D%20pat.length%20-%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20skip%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%20start%3B%20i%20%3C%3D%20lastIndex%3B%20i%20%2B%3D%20skip)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20skip%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20j%20%3D%20lastPatIndex%3B%20j%20%3E%3D%200%3B%20j--)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20char%3A%20number%20%3D%20text%5Bi%20%2B%20j%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(pat%5Bj%5D%20!%3D%3D%20char)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20skip%20%3D%20Math.max(1%2C%20j%20-%20right%5Bchar%5D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20break%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(skip%20%3D%3D%3D%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20i%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20-1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5BboyerMooreSearch%2C%20pattern.byteLength%5D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Simple%20usage%20example%0Aconst%20boyerMoore%20%3D%20new%20BoyerMoore(new%20Uint8Array(%5B0x12%2C%200x13%2C%200x14%5D))%3B%0Aconst%20indexes%20%3D%20boyerMoore.findIndexes(new%20Uint8Array(%5B0x01%2C%200x02%2C%200x12%2C%200x13%2C%200x14%5D))%3B%0Aconsole.log(indexes)%3B%0A%0A)

```
function asUint8Array(input) {
  if (input instanceof Uint8Array) {
    return input;
  } else if (typeof(input) === 'string') {
    // This naive transform only supports ASCII patterns. UTF-8 support
    // not necessary for the intended use case here.
    var arr = new Uint8Array(input.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      var c = input.charCodeAt(i);
      if (c > 127) {
        throw new TypeError("Only ASCII patterns are supported");
      }
      arr[i] = c;
    }
    return arr;
  } else {
    // Assume that it's already something that can be coerced.
    return new Uint8Array(input);
  }
}
function boyerMoore(patternBuffer) {
  // Implementation of Boyer-Moore substring search ported from page 772 of
  // Algorithms Fourth Edition (Sedgewick, Wayne)
  // http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/53substring/BoyerMoore.java.html
  /*
  USAGE:
     // needle should be ASCII string, ArrayBuffer, or Uint8Array
     // haystack should be an ArrayBuffer or Uint8Array
     var search = boyerMoore(needle);
     var skip = search.byteLength;
     var indexes = [];
     for (var i = search(haystack); i !== -1; i = search(haystack, i + skip)) {
       indexes.push(i);
     }
  */
  var pattern = asUint8Array(patternBuffer);
  var M = pattern.length;
  if (M === 0) {
    throw new TypeError("patternBuffer must be at least 1 byte long");
  }
  // radix
  var R = 256;
  var rightmost_positions = new Int32Array(R);
  // position of the rightmost occurrence of the byte c in the pattern
  for (var c = 0; c < R; c++) {
    // -1 for bytes not in pattern
    rightmost_positions[c] = -1;
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    // rightmost position for bytes in pattern
    rightmost_positions[pattern[j]] = j;
  }
  function boyerMooreSearch(txtBuffer, start, end) {
    // Return offset of first match, -1 if no match.
    var txt = asUint8Array(txtBuffer);
    if (start === undefined) start = 0;
    if (end === undefined) end = txt.length;
    var pat = pattern;
    var right = rightmost_positions;
    var lastIndex = end - pat.length;
    var lastPatIndex = pat.length - 1;
    var skip;
    for (var i = start; i <= lastIndex; i += skip) {
      skip = 0;
      for (var j = lastPatIndex; j >= 0; j--) {
        var c = txt[i + j];
        if (pat[j] !== c) {
          skip = Math.max(1, j - right[c]);
          break;
        }
      }
      if (skip === 0) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
  boyerMooreSearch.byteLength = pattern.byteLength;
  return boyerMooreSearch;
}
```